# iMacros and many results webpages

Tags: imacros

I want to fill in a form to search.

Some times there may be 0-19 results, it's ok, it works.

But as long as there's a button "next", I'd like to simulate click on it, then save the page as `[namefile]-2`, `[namefile]-3`, `[namefile]-4` and so on.

Any idea how you would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var macroClickNext;

macroClickNext ="CODE:";
//this is just example of button not like your case
macroClickNext +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Next";


var macroTestNext;

macroTestNext ="CODE:";
//this is just example of the button not like in your case
macroTestNext +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Next CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER";

var test=false;

while(true)
{

test=iimPlay(macroTestNext)

if (test>0)
{
iimPlay(macroNext)
}
else
{
break;
}

}
```

In your example this would do the job. It will click the Next button as long as it's on the page. `CONTENT:EVENT:MOUSEOVER`  is a simple event that hovers over a page element. If it's present it will return true , if not it will return false.

Comment: This implies not free iMacro (= I have to buy it)?

Comment: No, this is JavaScript and you don't have to buy anything. In JS you just "wrap" the imacros code and define it as a variable. But that is whole another level. :)

Comment: My "recorded" corresponding line is `TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Page<SP>suivante` . May I ask you just to modify your example to adapt it? After this I'll check your answer as valid, (many)³² thanks!

Comment: Your event doesn't work anymore (for the v.7.xx of iMacros). The solution I've found is to use **`CONTENT=EVENT:FAIL_IF_FOUND`** and to wait for the timeout, and just valid the corresponding error (if found then fail), something like `test=iimPlay(macroTestNext); if (test==-990) { } ` instead of your code `test=iimPlay(macroTestNext); if (test > 0) { } `... But it works. Thank you for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Hi, CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER works just fine for me. I tested it yesterday on project and logics worked. I don't know which version you used but mine is 7.6 . But if you want to move on to 8.24 do it. It's great in some ways although much slower.

Comment: Also make sure you are not putting SET !ERRORIGNORE YES with that macro since it will always return true and the code looses meaning.